# Hierachical clustering rules in R with hclust

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, distance

I am dealing with  cluster analysis. I got the next tree:

I have used the function hclust. Most of my variables are categorical, two of them are numeric. How to describe the features of each group if I want to assign a new individual to one of the groups?.

[image]